# Restore mysqldump on other server does not restore password

Tags: mysql, mariadb

On server A:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --add-drop-database > /nas/mydump.sql
```

On Server B:

```
mysql < /nas/mydump.sql
```

When I do a:

```
select user,host,password from mysql.user;
```

The password hashes are on both servers the same, but when I try to login it does not work:

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Am I missing something in the `mysqldump` command or is that a security feature?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following option:

```
--flush-privileges
```